# Python Google Sheets trouble with Writing to Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I am following Google API instructions here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing and having trouble 
with this block:

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheets/d/\
    spreadsheetId/values/sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
    values = {
    "range": "'Main'!A1:D5",
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
    ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],   #new row
    ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
    ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
    ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
    ],
} 

 which gives PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/\
 spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/values/\
 sheet1!A1:D5?\valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 This is copied directly from the API documentation.  Help! What is wrong?  
 Thanks.
```

Comment: Where is the python code that makes this "PUT ..." ? Can't help without it.

Comment: This is not python code. There is [another page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing) that gives the python API.

Comment: Definitely not python code. See instruction here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python for get started.

Comment: I'll give the entire code in a new question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [writing guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing) tells you to use this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

You on the other hand is using this:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheets/d/\
    spreadsheetId/values/sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

The URLS don't look alike. There is an unwanted `'\'` character in your URL.